# Resting a private variable that should not happen

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a strange problem I'm checking in my code behind the user if he is active or not with as simple if ..  in my Page_Load method as you can see here

```
    private TimeReport paramTR;
    private ZevUser zevUser;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ZevUser user = ZevUser.GetById(Int32.Parse(Session["SessionId"].ToString()));
        if (user == null)
        {
            this.Response.Redirect("~/About.aspx");
        }
        this.getParameters();

        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (paramTR.ZevUser.Active == 0)
            {
                this.Response.Redirect("~/TimeReporting/TimeReportPanel.aspx");
            }

            this.bindData();
        }


    }
```

But when I make a go throw to this method I get allays **nullreferenceexception** why so ever .. but the private ZevUser variable is not null it's full..

I really don't have a clue why is this happing, it would be really cool if someone could explain me this why this is happening

Thanks for help and fast answer

Comment: Session["SessionId"] can be null

Comment: what have you updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break your code down so you can debug it easier or add logging if you cannot debug this code locally.

Remember that when debugging something, the worse mistake you can make is to make assumptions.  Start from the beginning and follow the process through.  Don't assume that the problem *is* something and don't assume that the problem *can't be* something:

I've included a broken down, more readable version below.  You can now add logging around this or easily add breakpoints:

```
private TimeReport paramTR;
private ZevUser zevUser;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.getParameters();

    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        if ((this.paramTR != null) &&
            (this.paramTR.ZevUser != null) &&
            (this.paramTR.ZevUser.Active == 0))
        {
            this.Response.Redirect("~/TimeReporting/TimeReportPanel.aspx");
        }

        this.bindData();
    }

    string sessionId = Session["SessionId"] as string;

    if (sessionId != null)
    {
        int session = int32.Parse(sessionId);

        ZevUser user = ZevUser.GetById(session);

        if (user == null)
        {
            this.Response.Redirect("~/About.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Why are you passing the session id to `ZevUser.GetById()`?  I would expect this to take a user id, or for the method to be called something like `ZevUser.GetBySessionId()`.  At the moment it's quite confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This line is causing the issue:

```
ZevUser user = ZevUser.GetById(Int32.Parse(Session["SessionId"].ToString()));
```

This is because `Session["SessionId"]` can be null, and is null in this case.

If you are looking to get the SessionId that is set by ASP.net, then use `this.Session.SessionID` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/746732/51)).

If you are storing a value in `Session["SessionId"]` that you are trying to retrieve, then do a null-check first:

```
if (Session["SessionId"] != null) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider testing the `SessionId` variable before using it by doing something like that :

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["SessionId"].ToString()))
    ZevUser user = ZevUser.GetById(Int32.Parse(Session["SessionId"].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug your exception is to enable debug when the exception is thrown.
For this, go to Debug>>Exceptions

[image]

and then enable first four checkboxes (maybe) and then try debugging the project. You will be halted at the position from where the exception will be thrown.